# iPhone UILabel animation

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have a UILabel and when the value change in the label, I want to highlight it's background color from another color and exists for 2,3 seconds and get back to normal color.

Anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add quartzCore as a framework
2. Add an import QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h
3. Use this code

   ```
   - (void) initController
   {
         UIButton *myButton = [view viewWithTag:1]; // Just reference the button you have
         [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(animateLabel) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  
   }

   - (void) animateLabel
   {

     CABasicAnimation* highlightAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
     highlightAnim.toValue = (id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
     highlightAnim.duration = 2;          // In seconds 
     highlightAnim.autoreverses = YES;    // If you want to it to return to the normal color
     [label.layer addAnimation:highlightAnim forKey:nil];
    }
   ```

Comment: Hi Ron, 
Thanks alot. I'm going to try it now.

Comment: Hi Ron, I have tried this with a button. ( do the animation When the button click) . But nothing happens. What may be the issue?

Comment: You can't change the color of a UIButton with the type UIButtonRoundRect, hence you can't animate the color change.

If you need a button you need to create a UIButton with style UIButtonStyleCustom and create it's looks.

Comment: No no. I meant I did it for a UILabel, when I click on a UIButton. Sorry for miscommunication. Still no luck. Also how I detect the text change event?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but I updated the answer in a way that might answer your question.